# Any recommended resources for shell scripting on macs?

Tags: macos, shell, scripting

Somebody wants me to shell script something for his Mac. I don't even script on my Linux, and I'm not even sure what shell to expect on a Mac. What are some good resources for starting Mac shell scripting? Or any viable alternatives you can think of - as long as it doesn't require 3rd party software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/internet/opensource/opensourcescripting.html

Comment: Huh. ksh is on Mac now? I'm behind.

Comment: I'm not sure when that changed, but the page appears to have been last updated in 2005.

Comment: @The Roll: ksh appears to have been added in OS X v10.4.

Answer (score 2):

The shells on the Mac are the same ones you'd find on Linux; bash, tcsh, ksh, and zsh are installed by default.

Comment: I could have sworn it didn't have ksh. I guess that changed when I wasn't looking.